# How to get the full path of an image viewed in the default Gallery App on the Samsung Galaxy?

Tags: gallery, file-management

**The Android is the Samsung Galaxy S7.**

Can someone tell me how to get the **full path** of the files being displayed in the Gallery App?

I have tried to figure it out by creating a folder, placing picture in it, then browsing to the pictures in Gallery.  It shows the folder name, but doesn't show the path to the folder.

If I create a folder: `/sdcard/mypictures/`, it's show the images in an album called `mypictures`.  It doesn't show that the `mypictures` folder is off the root of `sdcard`.  If I make a subfolder in `/sdcard/mypictures/march2017`, it shows the images are in `march2017`.

I'm trying to figure this out because browsing a friends phone, we are trying to grap pictures from it.  We see them in Gallery, but can't figure out, of his years of storing and sorting pictures on where they are actually located.

I'm sure there is a way to get the path.  Hopefully someone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to get to the path by this message and steps provided by [beeshyams](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35765851#35765851).

**The menu button on the Samsung Galaxys is the hardware Return Key.**

The problem is that, there isn't an onscreen menu for the recent Samsung Galaxy androids.  I was stuck on the **3 dot menu** step.

The Samsung Galaxy has a hidden hardware menu.  Pressing and holding the **Return Button** activate the menu feature.

While having an image in view, press and hold the **Return Button**, this bring up a menu that include the **Details** option.  Clicking on Details brings up a lot of information on the image, including a map marked where it was taken.  It also shows a properties block that includes the **path** of the image.

Comment: Glad it is solved +1

Answer (score 1):

- Firstly, the option of installing a file explorer, as in my earlier solution (now deleted) was not tenable as the device from which pics were to copied is not OP's. OP edited his question to highlight using Gallery app only
- On my device Moto X Play with stock gallery app, the method is - When I open any of folders and select a pic, a tick mark appears and from the 3 dot menu → details → scrolling down I can see the path as `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/camera/xxx.jpg`. This information section follows information about the geo tagged information of pics
- On the chat, we could not find a way to get to the 3 dot menu on OP's device and OP found the way out using hardware keys as explained his answer